# How can I split a text in C# and keep the position of each part

Tags: c#, string, split

I want to split a large text based on delimiter.

I used:

```
string[] parts = text
  .Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine + "##" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

I would like to know the start position (character index of each part). I could search for each part in a loop:

```
int[] pos = new int[slides.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < slides.Length; i++)
{
    pos[i] = i == 0 ? text.IndexOf(slides[i]) : text.IndexOf(slides[i], pos[i-1] + 1);
}
```

Or I can search for the delimiters. I would like to know if there is a faster and better solution.

Comment: How do you define 'better and faster'? Often that's the one that is fastest to test/debug and for the next guy to understand. Unless you know you'll be processing millions of items it's usually best to ignore pure performance until it becomes a problem. The simple solution to get the start position of each part would be to use `IndexOf` to search for the delimiters.

Comment: This will not be very efficient for large strings. Though still not the most optimal solution but you could use this. Say `start[i]` is the start position of `parts[i]`. We can then say that `start[i + 1] = start[i] + parts[i].Length`. So start at `i = 0` with a starting index of `0` and work your way from there.

Comment: To add: I forgot the fact that the delimiters are in the original and not the `parts` so it becomes `start[i + 1] = [start[i] + parts[i].Length + {length of delimitor}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have just *one* delimiter and you *don't remove* empty items; why not just *sum* up lengths?

```
abc\r\n##defhhdsncdslcnslsc\r\n##pqr....
^        ^                       ^
0        abc.Length +            abc.Length + 
         delimiter.Length        delimiter.Length +  
                                 defhhdsncdslcnslsc.Length +
                                 delimiter.Length
```

Code (`item` and its `index`):

```
string delimiter = Environment.NewLine + "##"; 

int sum = 0;

var parts = text
  .Split(new string[] {delimiter}, StringSplitOptions.None)
  .Select(item => {
     int index = sum;
     sum = delimiter.Length + item.Length;

     return new {
       item,  // item
       index  // its index
     };  
   });
```

Or  (`2` separated arrays):

```
string[] parts = text.Split(new string[] {delimiter}, StringSplitOptions.None);
int[] pos = new pos[parts.Length];

for (int sum = 0, i = 0; i < parts.Length; sum += delimiter.Length + parts[i].Length, ++i) 
  pos[i] = sum;
```